# Openshift asynchronous wait for container to be running

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'm creating multiple pods at the same time in Openshift, and I also want to check the containers inside the pods are working correctly.
Some of these containers can take a while to start-up, and I don't want to wait for one pod to be fully running before starting up the other one.

Are there any Openshift / Kubernetes checks I can do to ensure a container has booted up, while also going ahead with other deployments?

Answer (score 1):

Please configure the [Liveness and Readiness Probes](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/liveness-and-readiness-probes)

> - Liveness : Under what circumstances is it appropriate to restart the pod?
> - Readiness : under what circumstances should we take the pod out of the list of service endpoints so that it no longer responds to
>   requests?

Answer (score 1):

`...Some of these containers can take a while to start-up`

Liveness probe is not a good option for containers that requires extended startup time, mainly because you have to set a long time to cater for startup; which is irrelevant after that - result to unable to detect problem on time during execution. Instead, you use [startup probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-startup-probes) to handle and detect problem during startup and handover to liveness probe upon success; or restart container according to its restartPolicy should the startup probe failed.